# BME280 Sensor Not Showing Up in i2cdetect

Tags: i2c

I have two components (one amplifier module and one BME280 from Adafruit) connected in parallel to SDA/SCL GPIOs on my Pi 4. However, when I run `i2cdetect -y 1`, only the address for the amplifier shows up.

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 4b -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I expect to see 0x77 too, which is the i2c address of the BME Sensor.

I have followed the [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bme280-humidity-barometric-pressure-temperature-sensor-breakout/python-circuitpython-test#step-2994996) for wiring and used my multimeter to check that the pins on BME280 have correct voltages.

*Pi 3V3 to sensor VIN
Pi 3V3 to sensor CS
Pi GND to sensor GND
Pi SCL to sensor SCK
Pi SDA to sensor SDI*

**No idea as to why 0x77 isn't showing up... any input would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: What's 0x4B? How is is wired to your RPi? How is your BME280 wired to your other I2C device? What pin is Vcc on your BME280 wired to?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question:I unplugged my Pi, and SSH'ed in and typed `i2cdetect -y 1`. Then both 0x77 and 0x4b showed up!! Not sure why this works, but it seems that rebooting can often help!